# MySQL left join empty result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: **terems** and **logs1015**.
Need to add data from **logs1015** to **terems** based on similar '*hash*' row.

This query works fine if '*SUM(insum)*' or '*SUM(outsum)* is larger than 0.
But if **logs1015** doesn't contain data with such '*hash*' then query result is empty.

What the mistake? Thanks

```
SELECT terems.*, 
    SUM(insum) as firstsum , 
    SUM(outsum) as secondsum 
    FROM terems 
    LEFT JOIN logs1015 USING(hash) 
    WHERE owner='1' 
        AND (type='stat') 
        AND (time BETWEEN 1445904000 AND 1445990400) 
    GROUP BY name 
    LIMIT 1000
```

Tables structure

```
*terems*: id(int),hash(varchar),name(varchar),owner(int)  
*logs1015*: id(int),hash(varchar),type(varchar),insum(int),outsum(int),time(varchar)
```

Comment: what are your tables structure?

Comment: are `owner`, `type` or `time` found from `logs1015`? If so, then you also need to check for null values to match the non-existent rows.

Comment: Edit your question and include *qualified column names* (so the table name is identified).

Comment: Edited. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When (left) outer joining, you must put the where clauses on the outer table in the join condition, otherwise you say that it must exist after joining. And then you have implicitly turned it into an inner join.

Also use aliases on your tables so you can easily spot these bugs.

Example:

```
SELECT t.name, 
    SUM(l.insum) as firstsum , 
    SUM(l.outsum) as secondsum 
FROM terems t
LEFT JOIN logs1015 l ON t.hash = l.hash
                     AND (l.type='stat') 
WHERE t.owner='1' 
    AND (t.time BETWEEN 1445904000 AND 1445990400) 
GROUP BY t.name 
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Just added table structures to the topic.
Your query gives the same result as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
"SELECT t.*, 
        SUM(l.insum) as firstsum , 
        SUM(l.outsum) as secondsum 
        FROM terems t
        LEFT JOIN logs1015 l ON 
            t.hash = l.hash
            AND (l.type='stat') 
            AND (l.time BETWEEN $fromstamp AND $tostamp)
        WHERE t.owner='$userid'    
        GROUP BY t.name 
        LIMIT 1000";
```

Thanks a lot!